# 条件によって処理が異なる1行（実行回数1回）のSQL文を作成したい

Tags: mysql, sql

当方SQL初心者です。

テーブル内に以下のデータが存在しており、`column_A`はユニークIDとします。

```
+----------+----------+
| column_A | column_B |
+----------+----------+
| 0001     | HOGE     |
| 0002     | FUGA     |
| 0003     | PIYO     |
+----------+----------+
```

既存データと挿入したいデータの`column_A`が重複しない場合はそのままデータを挿入し、
重複する場合はデータの更新を行いたいです。

管理上の都合により実行回数1回で済むSQL文を作りたいのですが、
知識不足で1行にまとめることができませんでした。わかる方がいらっしゃいましたら教えて頂きたいです。

**パターン1：既存データと挿入したいデータの`column_A`が重複しない場合**
挿入するデータ：`column_A='0004',column_B='BAKA'`

```
+----------+----------+
| column_A | column_B |
+----------+----------+
| 0001     | HOGE     |
| 0002     | FUGA     |
| 0003     | PIYO     |
| 0004     | BAKA     |
+----------+----------+
```

**パターン2：既存データと挿入したいデータの`column_A`が重複する場合**
挿入するデータ：`column_A='0001',column_B='AHO'`

```
+----------+----------+
| column_A | column_B |
+----------+----------+
| 0001     | AHO      |
| 0002     | FUGA     |
| 0003     | PIYO     |
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQLでは、主キーまたはユニークキーが重複しない場合は`Insert`、重複する場合は`Update`する仕組みとして[`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ステートメント`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/insert-on-duplicate.html)が用意されています。
下記の`パターン1`と`パターン2`の構文を参考にしてみてください。

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  `column_A` VARCHAR(4)  PRIMARY KEY,
  `column_B` VARCHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO my_table
  (`column_A`, `column_B`)
VALUES
  ('0001', 'HOGE'),
  ('0002', 'FUGA'),
  ('0003', 'PIYO');

-- パターン1
INSERT INTO my_table (column_A, column_B)
VALUES ('0004', 'FOO')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column_B = VALUES(column_B);

-- パターン2
INSERT INTO my_table (column_A, column_B)
VALUES ('0001', 'BAR')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column_B = VALUES(column_B);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from my_table;
```

| column_A | column_B |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | BAR |
| 0002 | FUGA |
| 0003 | PIYO |
| 0004 | FOO |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bQJ68Gu1uMv4jzZD5bXHhg/1)

Comment: 一度 INSERT ～ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ステートメントを使ってうまくいかず苦戦していましたが、
恥ずかしながら単にプライマリキーを設定していなかっただけでした。
ありがとうございました。